# Type Family Equivalent of `Eq`?

Tags: haskell

[Type Families with Class](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WjJdwL-VjXg&t=398s) shows:

[image]

As I incompletely understand, this slide shows 2 ways of implementing `Eq`: via a type class or type family.

I'm familiar with type classes and thus implemented `MyEq`:

```
class MyEq a where 
    eq :: a -> a -> Bool
```

But, when I tried to define the `type family` version, it failed to compile:

```
data Defined = Yes | No

type family IsEq (a :: *) :: Defined
```

due to:

```
TypeEq.hs:30:30: error:
    • Type constructor ‘Defined’ cannot be used here
        (Perhaps you intended to use DataKinds)
    • In the kind ‘Defined’
```

Please explain how to implement the `type family` version of the `Eq` type class.
Also, it'd be helpful, please, to show an implementation of such a `type family` instance (if that's even the right word).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is kind of neat, glad to have stumbled across this. For the interested, [here](http://www.itu.dk/people/paba/pubs/files/serrano15haskell-slides.pdf) is the slide deck and [here](https://dspace.library.uu.nl/bitstream/handle/1874/320701/p129_serrano.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y) is the paper. This is a usual case of needing some language extensions.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, TypeFamilies, TypeOperators, ConstraintKinds #-}

data Defined = Yes | No

type family IsEq (a :: *) :: Defined

type Eq a = IsEq a ~ Yes
```

Then, the "implementation" of this are instances like

```
type instance IsEq () = Yes      -- '()' is an instance of 'Eq'
type instance IsEq Int = Yes     -- 'Int' is an instance of 'Eq'
type instance IsEq [a] = IsEq a  -- '[a]' is an instance of 'Eq' is 'a' is
```

You can "try" them out at GHCi:

```
ghci> :kind! IsEq [Int]
IsEq [Int] :: Defined
= Yes
```

But the paper and slide deck doesn't really worry too much about actually providing an equality function. (It mentions storing it in a field of `Yes`). So, why is this interesting if it isn't even ready to provide class methods? Because

- it makes for a better mechanism than overlapping classes
- backtracking search is easier than with typeclasses
- it makes it possible to fail early with nice error message (encoded as a field in the `No` constructor)

Comment: Thanks for this helpful answer, Alec! Could you please say a bit more as to what `IsEq a ~ Yes` means? Also, it appears to me that the `:kind! IsEq [Int]` is a type level computation. Does that mean that applying `IsEq` to an actual value, e.g. `[1,2,3]`, does not make sense?

Comment: @KevinMeredith `IsEq a ~ Yes` is an equality constraint - it holds only if the LHS and RHS are equal. Here, we want to define the constraint `Eq a` to hold iff `IsEq a` and `Yes` are the equal. And yes applying `IsEq` to an actual value like `[1,2,3]` makes no sense - `IsEq` is a type family (a limited type-level function), not a (value-level) function.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `DataKinds` As a language extension (i.e. to the top of the file under a "language" pragma) as the error message suggests.

I haven't watched the talk, but iiuc, `Defined` is just `Bool`, where `Yes` is `True`. So if you enable DataKinds, you can just use `IsEq a ~ 'True` (and the apostrophe before True just means "this is a type").

Some background: what this extension does is "raise" every value of any algebraic datatypes (i.e. Declared with `data`, but not `GADTs`, iiuc) into its own type; and then raises each type into its own kind (a "kind" in Haskell is the "type of types"), i.e. not of "kind *" (pronounced "kind star"), which is the kind of normal Haskell values that exist at runtime.

btw:

`[Bool] :: *` means that "a list of liens is a type". and `[] :: * -> *` means that the type constructor for lists has kind "type to type", i.e. "once you give List a single type, you get back a type".